# Debugging CORS requests which fail to set cookies even with CORS headers and withCredentials=true

Tags: cookies, cors, xmlhttprequest

There are many questions on StackOverflow of users making a CORS request which doesn't properly set cookies. I'm having the same problem, but I'm wondering if Chrome or another browser provides a method to diagnose and understand why the cookies aren't set.

I'm finding all kinds of things that can cause this: missing CORS headers, missing `withCredentails=true`, situations across https secure boundaries, certain flags on the cookies... I want to understand what Chrome is doing instead of just guessing why it doesn't work.

---

Here's my specific problem, but really I'm after a process to understand not just the fix.

#### Domain Creating Request:

Note withCredentails = true.

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
    callback(xmlhttp);
  }
};
xmlhttp.open('POST', url, true);
xmlhttp.withCredentials = true;
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xmlhttp.send(payload);
```

#### Request:

Notice that Chrome doesn't show any Set-Cookie headers for the request.
[image]

#### Curl of same request:

But if I right-click > copy > cUrl and execute here are the raw headers include Set-Cookie:

```
curl 'http://satellite:6988/medic/login' -H 'Referer: http://upstream:5988/medic/login?redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fupstream%3A5988%2Fmedic%2F_design%2Fmedic%2F_rewrite%2F%23%2Fmessages%2Fcontact%3A13863168-be61-418a-aea1-1b19b9a5af39' -H 'Origin: http://upstream:5988' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.67 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8' --data-binary '{"user":"worker","password":"dSNH1sv2jzdB"}' --compressed -v
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to satellite (127.0.0.1) port 6988 (#0)
> POST /medic/login HTTP/1.1
> Host: satellite:6988
> Accept: */*
> Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
> Referer: http://upstream:5988/medic/login?redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fupstream%3A5988%2Fmedic%2F_design%2Fmedic%2F_rewrite%2F%23%2Fmessages%2Fcontact%3A13863168-be61-418a-aea1-1b19b9a5af39
> Origin: http://upstream:5988
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.67 Safari/537.36
> Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
> Content-Length: 43
> 
* upload completely sent off: 43 out of 43 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://upstream:5988
< Vary: Origin, Accept-Encoding
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS, HEAD, DELETE
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept, authorization, content-type, origin, referer, x-csrf-token
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< Set-Cookie: AuthSession=d29ya2VyOjVDMDdEMjgwOj06hJxoYrYGtUxNa3ImYd1AZ7Vw; Path=/
< Set-Cookie: userCtx=%7B%22name%22%3A%22worker%22%2C%22roles%22%3A%5B%22chv%22%5D%7D; Max-Age=31536000; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 05 Dec 2019 13:28:32 GMT
< Set-Cookie: satelliteServer=; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 16
< ETag: W/"10-oV4hJxRVSENxc/wX8+mA4/Pe4tA"
< Date: Wed, 05 Dec 2018 13:28:32 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
* Connection #0 to host satellite left intact
{"success":true}
```

Comment: `I want to understand what Chrome is doing instead of just guessing why it doesn't work.` OMG yes, I can't believe that it's so incredibly hard to find this information, and so sad that all the answers online basically amount to guesswork. I'm dealing with a similar issue. The `Set-Cookie` looks fine, but it's just.. not..stored, with no information shown whatsoever. It's hopeless and frustrating. I'm just going to go for a workaround, any workaround...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Chrome console is helpful for understanding problems with CORS headers. Since it writes clear descriptive headers when a request is fully blocked.

For my particular scenario, I used chrome://net-internals/#events which contains cookie related events to understand that the Set-Cookie headers are omiited from developer tools but were being served, received, and properly set.

My issue was that I was setting `options.credentials=true` when using `fetch` on requests after the cookies were set instead of the required `options.credentials='include'`.

Comment: Great pointer to `chrome://net-internals/#events`. It redirects to a logging tool now, but it really provides a whole lot of extra information. Unfortunately, in my case at least, it still only provided a hint, that `DO_NOT_SAVE_COOKIES` is set on the initial request, without explaining why, and due to its relative obscurity I haven't been able to find any more info online. But at least it's another step in some direction!

Comment: Did you finally understand why this flag was present?